# Parse String to Date in java

Tags: java, date, string-to-datetime

I have date like `mm-dd-yyy` in string format and I am trying to convert the same to Date object in java,
Two ways I tried in

1. sending the date format as `"mm-dd-yyy"` which is returning the wrong
   date, it always returns month Jan even though the month in the
   string is not "01"
2. sending the date format as `"MM-dd-yyy"` will return the correct date
   as expected.

But I want to understand why the first approach returning wrong?
Can any body tell me the reason.

Comment: Are you asking why `MM` and not `mm`? Read the Javadoc...

Comment: mm is used as a place holder for minutes.. MM is used for month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date and time formats are specified by pattern strings. Within the pattern strings, `m` is interpreted as **minute in hour**, and `M` is interpreted as **Month in year**.

Perhaps you should read [JavaDoc API spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

And you should check that the year of parsed date object is what you intended to. Since your string is `MM-dd-yyy`, `"02-12-014"`(which should be `2014-02-12` is actually interpreted as `0014-02-12`, which can be not your intended result.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
M   Month in year 

m   Minute in hour
```